# symfony 3.4 Type error: Argument 1 passed to ... must be an instance of DateTime, null given,

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

In the entity the date time is decalared:

```
 /**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @ORM\Column(name="task_date_start", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
 private $taskDateStart;
```

in the form

```
$builder->add('taskDateStart', DateType::class, [
    "widget" => "single_text",
    "html5" => false,
    "format" => "dd-MM-yyyy"  ,
    "attr" => ["class" => "js-datepicker"], 
    "required" => false                                                    
]);
```

i've this error when inserting null in to the field

> Argument 1 passed to ... must be an instance of DateTime, null given

Comment: What is `...`, your entity ?Can you edit your post and add your entity setter? Note than you should use the `{}` symbol in the editor to format your code properly (I did it for this post ;)).

Comment: Most probably you have method `setTaskDateStart(\DateTime $taskDateStart)` which does not allow passing `null` to it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by modifying the setter (new setter without prototype):

```
 function setTaskDateStart(\DateTime $taskDateStart = null ) {
     $this->taskDateStart = $taskDateStart;
 }
```

become

```
 function setTaskDateStart( $taskDateStart ) {
     $this->taskDateStart = $taskDateStart;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Better solution is to allow set the null and let the validation reports the error.

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @ORM\Column(name="task_date_start", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
 private $taskDateStart;
```

and

```
 function setTaskDateStart(?\DateTime $taskDateStart) {
     $this->taskDateStart = $taskDateStart;
 }
```